# Commercial usage of sentence-transformers/multi-qa-mpnet-base-cos-v1

Tags: licensing, commercial, artificial-intelligence

We are trying to use a `HuggingFace Embedding model` - [multi-qa-mpnet-base-cos-v1](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/multi-qa-mpnet-base-cos-v1) for an internal Large Language Model powered application. While reading the documentation it says (not verbatim):

For the multi-qa mpnet model, of the training datasets used, some of them are not for commercial use.

For instance, [GOOAQ](https://github.com/allenai/gooaq) and [Yahoo! answers](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/soumikrakshit/yahoo-answers-dataset).

For GOOAQ, it states:

> NOTE: This dataset should not be used for any commercial purposes.

For one of the Yahoo datasets used for multi-qa-mpnet-base-cos-v1, in the **readme.txt** file, it states:

> The original Yahoo! Answers corpus can be obtained through the Yahoo! Research Alliance Webscope program. The dataset is to be used for approved non-commercial research purposes by recipients who have signed a Data Sharing Agreement with Yahoo!.

*multi-qa-mpnet-base-cos-v1* was also trained on **MS MARCO** which also has the same licence issues.

Does this automatically mean that the model itself is "tainted" and therefore we cannot use it for embeddings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using output of a CC BY-NC AI algorithm in a commercial product?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/8019/using-output-of-a-cc-by-nc-ai-algorithm-in-a-commercial-product)