# Code workflow is licensed Apache 2, but the data generated is BY-NC-SA. Can I recreate the data and commercialize it?

Tags: license-compatibility, apache-2.0, license, cc-by-nc-sa

There is a website that offers both a codebase to process some arbitrary public data (as Apache 2.0), but licensed the output data of the workflow as BY-NC-SA 4.0 (at least the processed data on the website). Can I re-produce the output data with the (free) codebase, and integrate it into a commercial offering? Presumably, the data is considered a derivate of the code, and should be covered by Apache 2.0

Answer (score 2):

IANAL/IANYL, but your presumption is wrong; the output of a program is [not generally subject to the licence of the program](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same).  Instead, the output data are generally considered a derivative of the input data.

So in this case, as long as the input data aren't subject to any kind of restrictive licence, you should indeed be able to download a copy of the Apache-2.0-licensed code, run it yourself, and recreate a copy of the output data which doesn't have a restrictive licence attached.  You don't give us any information about the input data, so it's hard to say anything more precise than this.