# Using data generated by an open-source GPLv3.0 software

Tags: gpl-3, open-data

I'm looking to build a web app that allows users to upload and share JSON data.  The JSON data generated and exported by an open-source app licensed under GPLv3.0.

Before I begin building, I want to ensure that this data is useable in the above manner and there aren't any issues with this concept.  Is the data generated by an open-source GPLv3.0 software free to use?

Thank you.

Comment: What inputs are given to the program in order to generate these JSON outputs, and what licence are those inputs under?

Comment: The program builds temperature curves generated by thermocouples(thermometers) that interface with the program.  The program saves the data in their own file extension, though it can also be exported to JSON.  Thank you

Comment: Then hopefully your question is answered by [Is the output of an open source program licensed the same](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same), which should tell you that the licence on the software doesn't generally affect the licence on the output.  Could you read that question and the answers thoroughly, and either let us know that it answered your question, or edit your question to make it clear what you still want to know?  Thanks!