# Can I use GPL v3 licensed software to create my commercial product?

Tags: licensing, gpl-3, commercial

Note that I am **not** modifying or redistributing the GPL3 licensed software, nor am I selling it. I am merely *using it* to create a different product, which contains the output of the software for commercial purposes.

More precisely, I am planning to use [this Latex package](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) that creates nice looking graphs. I then intend to use the graphs created by this software package in a commercial manner.

Can I do so under the terms of its license? Am I going to be in trouble for doing so? Do I need to explicitly mention the package name within the product?

Comment: Does [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same) shed any light on your query?

Comment: @MadHatter Yes it does thank you!

Comment: Glad we could answer your question, and I've closed it as a duplicate; hope that's OK.  If I may, it's worth doing a bit of digging before posting a question here; we've stored up a fair bit of knowledge over the years!

Comment: @MadHatter Yes that's perfectly fine, thank you. I will definitely be more careful next time.