# Licensing for a physical product developed from MIT code

Tags: licensing, mit, copyright

I have a developed a Book using outputs from parts of code from a MIT licence repository.

Where would I show or put the copyright licence? On the product? Or create a website?

Or because it is not longer software the MIT licence is invalid? Alongside the physical book, I will also be publishing a digital copy.

To be clear, the book does not contain the code but is derived from the output from the code.

Comment: See also: [Is the output of an open source program licensed the same?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same) Although you say your book is derived from the code, technically I don't think that's the case, unless the book output itself contains significant parts of the software code, as a result of the output process (which I think is pretty rare for document tools).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not distribute the source or the programme itself of an MIT-licensed programme, you do not have to show the copyright license. If you like to acknowledge the software's role in creation of the book, do that in its acknowledgement section, possibly with a link to the sources (that's the decent thing to do, IMHO).

The [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) is short and IMHO hard to mis-understand. Excerpt quote of the relevant paragraph:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

As such: place it (or better keep it) where you distribute the software with which you created the book.