# Are works created using GPLv2 licensed code considered derivative of the code?

Tags: gpl, gpl-2, license

Consider that I write some code which generates 3D models, and release it using the GPLv2 license. Someone else then sees value in my code but wishes to change it and so they modify it to their specific purposes and use it to create some 3D models which they then sell as part of their business. Does the fact that the models were created using GPLv2 licensed code require that the modifications made to the code be released as open source, or can the modifier keep their changes private but sell the models? Does GPLv2 allow me to protect their right to create commercial products with it whilst enforcing that their modifications on the code cannot be released commercially?

Comment: Welcome to OpenSource.SE!  Have you read [Is the output of an open source program licensed the same](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same)?  Does it leave any of your question unanswered?

Comment: You seem to be asking about two different things -- 1. someone modifies your generator code (which is GPL), and 2. someone uses the software (the executable GPL code) to create 3D models.  Each one of those has a different answer.

Comment: @MadHatter Yes it does. Thank you very much.