# Is it free to use Node.js with addon?

Tags: license

OS: Windows

I want to build an app for commercial usage which needs to call a library written in C. The only way (as far as I know) is writing a Node.js addon which needs Visual Studio Tools to build it. But the build tool is not free. Does it mean that I cannot use it for commercial usage?

What if using another package like https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi? It's MIT licensed but still built via Visual Studio Tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the output of an open source program licensed the same?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/is-the-output-of-an-open-source-program-licensed-the-same) While the title refers to open source licenses, note that the answers are general to _any_ software.

Comment: You don't need Visual Studio Tools to build a node.js addon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you aren't bundling VS Tools in your application, the fact that they aren't free is inconsequential. The built addon isn't a derived work of the toolchain, and you can distribute it under whatever license you see fit.